# Checkbox on header group Datawindow Powerbuilder

Tags: checkbox, header, powerbuilder, datawindow

Why checkbox is not working on header group?but it is working on detail. Is there a code to manipulate the checkbox properties inside the header group of datawindow?

Comment: I don't believe that any sort of data manipulation can be performed in the header band. I believe that all bands except DETAIL are read-only.

Comment: You can change properties using Modify function or the corresponding dot notation for datawindow object properties. But generally what you want to do isn't going to be easy unless you want to jump through hoops- a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I put a column named "mycheckbox" in the header band and changed the edit type to checkbox. I added this code in the clicked event of the datawindow control to toggle the checkbox.

```
    if dwo.name = "mycheckbox" then
        long ll_row
        any la_off, la_on, la_value 
        ll_row = long( Object.DataWindow.FirstRowOnPage )
        if ll_row > 0 then
            la_value = Object.mycheckbox[ll_row]
            la_on   = Object.mycheckbox.CheckBox.On
            la_off  = Object.mycheckbox.CheckBox.Off
            if la_value = la_on then
                la_value = la_off
            else
                la_value = la_on
            end if
            Object.mycheckbox[ll_row] = la_value
        end if
    end if
```

Note:
This only changes the value for the first row in the datawindow. If there are many rows and you scroll down, the checkbox may change.

This code toggles the values for all of the rows.

```
    if dwo.name = "mycheckbox" then
        any la_off, la_on, la_value
        long ll_row, ll_rows
        ll_row = long( Object.DataWindow.FirstRowOnPage )
        if ll_row > 0 then
            la_value = Object.mycheckbox[ll_row]
            la_on   = Object.mycheckbox.CheckBox.On
            la_off  = Object.mycheckbox.CheckBox.Off
            if la_value = la_on then
                la_value = la_off
            else
                la_value = la_on
            end if
            ll_rows = Rowcount( )
            for ll_row = 1 to ll_rows
                Object.mycheckbox[ll_row] = la_value
            next
        end if
    end if
```